# Memoisation with auxiliary parameter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

I have a recursive function `f` that takes two parameters `x` and `y`. The function is uniquely determined by the first parameter; the second one merely makes things easier.

I now want to memoise that function w.r.t. it's first parameter while ignoring the second one. (I.e. `f` is evaluated at most one for every value of `x`)

What is the easiest way to do that? At the moment, I simply define an array containing all values recursively, but that is a somewhat ad-hoc solution. I would prefer some kind of memoisation combinator that I can just throw at my function.

EDIT: to clarify, the function `f` takes a pair of integers and a list. The first integer is some parameter value, the second one denotes the index of an element in some global list `xs` to consume.

To avoid indexing the list, I pass the partially consumed list to `f` as well, but obviously, the invariant is that if the first parameter is `(m, n)`, the second one will always be `drop n xs`, so the result is uniquely determined by the first parameter.

Just using a memoisation combinator on the partially applied function will not work, since that will leave an unevaluated thunk `\xs -> …` lying around. I could probably wrap the two parameters in a datatype whose `Eq` instance ignores the second value (and similarly for other instances), but that seems like a very ad-hoc solution. Is there not an easier way?

EDIT2: The concrete function I want to memoise:

```
g :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
g xs n = f 0 n
  where f :: Int -> Int -> Int
        f _ 0 = 0
        f m n
            | m == length xs  = 0
            | w > n           = f (m + 1) n
            | otherwise       = maximum [f (m + 1) n, v + f (m + 1) (n - w)]
          where (w, v) = xs !! m
```

To avoid the expensive indexing operation, I instead pass the partially-consumed list to `f` as well:

```
g' :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
g' xs n = f xs 0 n
  where f :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> Int
        f []           _ _ = 0
        f _            _ 0 = 0
        f ((w,v) : xs) m n
            | w > n           = f xs (m + 1) n
            | otherwise       = maximum [f xs (m + 1) n, v + f xs (m + 1) (n - w)]
```

Memoisation of `f` w.r.t. the list parameter is, of course, unnecessary, since the list does not (morally) influence the result. I would therefore like the memoisation to simply ignore the list parameter.

Comment: did you look at the [Haskell Wiki on Memoization](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization) yet? - Aside from this it would probably help to see your function (or at least the signature) - also if you only need the second parameter internally you should hide it - for example by wrapping it inside one with only the first parameter

Comment: This [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.7/docs/Data-Function-Memoize.html) would probably interest you. This library gives you the function `memoFix :: Memoizable a => ((a -> v) -> a -> v) -> a -> v` which will memoize a function of a single arguement written in open recursive form. Note that it doesn't care about its return type at all, i.e. `v` can be a function itself.

Comment: But that function it returns will be evaluated each time a parameter is passed to it again, will it not?

Comment: If the second argument is not used or determined from the first why not make the function take 1 argument (perhaps wrap the 2 argument function) and use any of the memo-techniques linked above.

Comment: @ManuelEberl If you have a function `go :: (Int -> Char -> String) -> Int -> Char -> String` for example, then your desired function is `memoFix go :: Int -> Char -> String`, this function will be evaluated at most once for each `Int` parameter but will potentially re-evaluated for the `Char` parameter. You could also have `memoFix2 go :: Int -> Char -> Bool` which memoizes both parameters.

Comment: I updated my question to address these comments.

Comment: I don't see what the invariant inside your function has to do with memoization, the compiler and runtime know nothing about your invariant. If the list needs to memoized as well, use `memoFix2` or simply curry the function. Can you include the function you are trying to memoize? Maybe that will make things easier.

Comment: All right, I added some code.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is unnecessarily complicated. You don't need the index `m` at all:

```hs
foo :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
foo []         _ = 0
foo _          0 = 0
foo ((w,v):xs) n
    | w > n      = foo xs n
    | otherwise  = foo xs n `max` foo xs (n - w) + v
```

Now if you want to memoize `foo` then both the arguments must be considered (as it should be).

We'll use the [monadic memoization mixin](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/wcook/Drafts/2009/sblp09-memo-mixins.pdf) method to memoize `foo`:

1. First, we create an uncurried version of `foo` (because we want to memoize both arguments):

   ```hs
   foo' :: ([(Int, Int)], Int) -> Int
   foo' ([],       _) = 0
   foo' (_,        0) = 0
   foo' ((w,v):xs, n)
       | w > n       = foo' (xs, n)
       | otherwise   = foo' (xs, n) `max` foo' (xs, n - w) + v
   ```
2. Next, we monadify the function `foo'` (because we want to thread a memo table in the function):

   ```hs
   foo' :: Monad m => ([(Int, Int)], Int) -> m Int
   foo' ([],       _) = return 0
   foo' (_,        0) = return 0
   foo' ((w,v):xs, n)
       | w > n        = foo' (xs, n)
       | otherwise    = do
           a <- foo' (xs, n)
           b <- foo' (xs, n - w)
           return (a `max` b + v)
   ```
3. Then, we open the self-reference in `foo'` (because we want to call the memoized function):

   ```hs
   type Endo a = a -> a

   foo' :: Monad m => Endo (([(Int, Int)], Int) -> Int)
   foo' _    ([],       _) = return 0
   foo' _    (_,        0) = return 0
   foo' self ((w,v):xs, n)
       | w > n             = foo' (xs, n)
       | otherwise         = do
           a <- self (xs, n)
           b <- self (xs, n - w)
           return (a `max` b + v)
   ```
4. We'll use the following memoization mixin to memoize our function `foo'`:

   ```hs
   type Dict a b m = (a -> m (Maybe b), a -> b -> m ())

   memo :: Monad m => Dict a b m -> Endo (a -> m b)
   memo (check, store) super a = do
       b <- check a
       case b of
           Just b  -> return b
           Nothing -> do
               b <- super a
               store a b
               return b
   ```
5. Our dictionary (memo table) will use the `State` monad and a `Map` data structure:

   ```hs
   import Prelude hiding (lookup)
   import Control.Monad.State
   import Data.Map.Strict

   mapDict :: Ord a => Dict a b (State (Map a b))
   mapDict = (check, store) where
       check a   = gets (lookup a)
       store a b = modify (insert a b)
   ```
6. Finally, we combine everything to create a memoized function `memoFoo`:

   ```hs
   import Data.Function (fix)

   type MapMemoized a b = a -> State (Map a b) b

   memoFoo :: MapMemoized ([(Int, Int)], Int) Int
   memoFoo = fix (memo mapDict . foo')
   ```
7. We can recover the original function `foo` as follows:

   ```hs
   foo :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
   foo xs n = evalState (memoFoo (xs, n)) empty
   ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course I don't need the index parameter, but if I use the list directly, I have to do list comparison with every map lookup instead of just integer comparison. I don't know a lot about memoisation, but this looks quite complicated, and I wonder if doing things this explicitly has drawbacks – does the use of explicit mutable state make parallelisation impossible?